# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo Android Studio Error

Tags: java, android

I am newbie ... I ve been trying to create a simple program but it keeps failing so I need some help with this error... what is wrong ?

the error i get is :

```
08-20 20:08:59.422 6192-6192/com.example.raduc.anew E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.example.raduc.anew, PID: 6192
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.raduc.anew/com.example.raduc.anew.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:116)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:201)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.example.raduc.anew.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:17)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1215)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2441) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5345) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.raduc.anew/
```

the activity:

```
package com.example.raduc.anew;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    EditText nr1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr);
}
```

and my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.raduc.anew.MainActivity">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.raduc.anew">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It's just a simple try to read someth from a EditText object but I dont't know why I get this error only when I set up a variable...

I

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: Is your `EditText nr1` outside of any method in the class or just a typo. Your question seems incomplete at several places.

Comment: @CommonsWare I did

Comment: @Shaishav I am just trying to get the text from the EditText... and this is the first step...

Comment: Use that space for context based variable declaration, not definition. Check Gabe's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EditText nr1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nr);
```

That has to be inside onCreate.  At init time, the context isn't set up so it won't work (a ontent view hasn't been set so at best it would return null, but the Activity isn't a valid context until onCreate is called so you can get all sorts of problems by using it too early).

Answer (score 0):

Please, put your EditText definition inside OnCreate method and have some tea before you start :)